# How to filter related objects?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have two models:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length='255', blank=False, db_index=True)

class GameImage(models.Model):

    TYPES = (
        ('small_image', 'Small Image'),
        ('medium_image', 'Medium Image'),
        ('feature_image', 'Feature Image'),
        ('subfeature_image', 'Sub-feature Image'),
        ('sc1', 'Screenshot 1'),
        ('sc2', 'Screenshot 2'),
        ('sc3', 'Screenshot 3'),
    )

    game = models.ForeignKey("Game", related_name="images", editable=False)
    image = ImageField(upload_to=gameimage_storage_path, max_length=255)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=TYPES, db_index=True)
```

If I do

```
games = Games.objects.prefetch_related('images').all()
```

It will attach all 'images' related objects, if I do:

```
games = Games.objects.prefetch_related('images').filter(images__type__contains='small_image').all()
```

It will show games which have images of type 'small_image', but still will load all GameImage objects related to a game.

How can I load a list of Games, where every game will have GameImages related object of type='small_image' only (it won't load other GameImage objects, related to a game)? I can do this via raw sql, but how to do this via Django ORM? Please help.

**UPDATE.**
Here is the SQL query I want to achieve via ORM:

```
SELECT * FROM game g LEFT JOIN gameimage i ON g.id = i.game_id AND i.type = 'small_image';
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Join

```
GameImage.objects.filter(img_type='small_image').select_related('game')
```

#### Left join game

```
from django.db.models import Q

GameImage.objects.filter(
    Q(img_type='small_image') | 
    Q(game__isnull=True)
).select_related('game')
```

#### Left join game image

```
Game.objects.filter(
    Q(images__img_type='small_image') |
    Q(id__isnull=True)
).select_related('images')
```

Comment: Still not what I need, last one was closer, but produces ***SELECT * FROM game g LEFT JOIN gameimage i ON g.id = i.game_id WHERE i.type = small_image*** instead of needed ***SELECT * FROM game g LEFT JOIN gameimage i ON g.id = i.game_id AND i.type = 'small_image'***

Comment: Which database are you using? The last one returns what you need on sqlite3.

Comment: mysql 5.5, that's strange that per your words in sqlite it produces what I want and in mysql it is different, however, didn't try it on sqlite... Please note that I have double condition in JOIN, that's what I need to achieve, not a WHERE condition

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo, but your game column is a foreign key to `GameNode` instead of `Game`.  I'm FKing to `Game`.  Unless the initial code in the question is incomplete, there might be something missing in my answer.

Comment: Yes, there is a typo, fixed. You FKed to Game and it is right FKing :)

Comment: your query will return a game which has 'small_image' and it is not guarantee that it will not have any other image associated with it. My query only return those game objects which has only single related image of type `small_image`.

Comment: I need to return a game and a small_image of it, if it exists, if not, I need a NULL instead. The thing is a game has lots of images attached to it, but in some cases I need to load a game object and only a small image for it (if exists), think of it like a list of latest games: you want to get a game title with a slug + small image.

Answer (score 0):

So you want all games but want to check if the game has small_image or not without loading extra related images:

models.py:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

Class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length='255', blank=False, db_index=True)

    def get_small_image(self):
        try:
            return self.images.get(type='small_image')
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return None
```

views.py:

```
games = Game.objects.all()
for game in games:
    small_image = game.get_small_image()
    if small_image:
        print small_image.image.url
    else:
        print 'there is no small image for this game'
```

Comment: no no, this approach generates very complex SQL query! I need to get similar SQL to what I showed at the bottom of my question (in Update question)

Comment: Does it matters? Have you calculated the time taken by it?

Comment: Why do I need a complex query instead of one simple? It even doesn't needed to be calculated to understand that this is not what I need.

Comment: Does a custom method is useful for you? Check my updated answer

Comment: I do appreciate your efforts, but this is not what I need. I'll try to be more descriptful. We have a game object. Every game can have multiple images attached to it (via GameImage). Now what I need, is to show a list of (let's say) 10 latest games. Next to every game I want to show its small image (if it exists). I could just query for games and load all images attached to every game via select_related or prefetch_related, but this is unefficient. Instead, I want to load image of 'small_type' only (if it exists). That's all I need. I already showed SQL which I want to generate.

Comment: Ha ha.. I understands your requirements. But if you see closely. It is exactly doing what you want. It is only loading game objects and when needed you can get only a single small image object by using method get_small_image. You can take this approach to the template also.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21609/discussion-between-aamir-adnan-and-timus83)